# Chamar página pelo HREF e carregar no IFRAME o id de outra página

Tags: css, html5

Galera, 
Veja se é possível essa situação em HTML5 e CSS:

Tenho 3 arquivos:
index.html
servicos.html
desc_servicos.html

Obs.: todos os arquivos dentro de uma mesma pasta.

No arquivo **index.html** há um link para a página **servicos.html**.
Dentro do **servicos.html** há um *Iframe* com src para desc_servicos.html.
Já no **desc_servicos.html** há várias *sections* com os respectivos ID's.

Há possibilidade de chamar a página **servicos.html** passando o ID de uma section, do arquivo **desc_servicos.html**, para ser carregado no *IFRAME*?

Tenho ciência dessa opção e sei que funciona quando está na mesma página, mas **não** tenho ciência quando se fala de várias páginas.

```
<a href="desc_servicos.html#id" target="nome_iframe">Agente</a>
```

Desculpa se ficou confuso a explicação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com páginas `.html`, você pode fazer isso usando JavaScript. Pode fazer desta forma, seguindo os passos:

**1.** Adicione a *hash* com o `id` da `div` que você irá carregar no `href` do link do `index.html`:

```
<a href="servicos.html#id_da_div">Serviços</a>
```

**2.** Na página `servicos.html` capture a *hash* com `window.location.hash`. Mas crie dois `iframe`s, um sem `src` e o outro oculto com `display: none` com a página `desc_servicos.html`.

> **Por que dois iframes sendo um oculto?** O que não é oculto irá receber a `div` do outro que é oculto. Isso porque o `iframe` oculto é
>   que irá carregar a página `desc_servicos.html` e não precisa aparecer,
>   pois ela será toda carregada para que se possa pegar a `div` desejada.

Ficaria assim:

```
<iframe id="frame" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" style="display: none;" src="desc_servicos.html"></iframe>
```

E inclua o script abaixo (no final do `body`) da página `servicos.html`:

```
<script>
var iFrame = document.body.querySelector("#frame");
var iFrame2 = document.body.querySelector("#frame2");
var div_id = window.location.hash;
iFrame2.onload = function(){ // aguarda o iframe2 carregar

   // insere a div no iframe visível
   iFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = iFrame2.contentWindow.document.querySelector(div_id).outerHTML;
   iFrame2.outerHTML = ''; // remove o iframe2 do DOM
}
</script>
```

**Resumindo:**

Na página `index.html` (substitua `id_da_div` pelo `id` da `div` lá do `iframe` que você quer pegar):

```
<a href="servicos.html#id_da_div">Serviços</a>
```

Na página `servicos.html`:

```
<iframe id="frame" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" style="display: none;" src="desc_servicos.html"></iframe>

<script>
var iFrame = document.body.querySelector("#frame");
var iFrame2 = document.body.querySelector("#frame2");
var div_id = window.location.hash;
iFrame2.onload = function(){ // aguarda o iframe2 carregar

   // insere a div no iframe visível
   iFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = iFrame2.contentWindow.document.querySelector(div_id).outerHTML;
   iFrame2.outerHTML = ''; // remove o iframe2 do DOM
}
</script>
```

Comment: Legal broder!... qq coisa é só chamar

Comment: dvd,    funcionou perfeitamente. **Muito obrigado pela instrução e parabéns pela didática no ensino**.   Agora tenho que realizar a formatação das informações chamadas, pois acredito que quando carrega a _frame2_ e envia para _frame_ acredito que perco a formação.   Ainda não tenho conhecimento em JavaScript, mas chegarei lá!

Comment: A resposta completa acima!!